# Android studio не видит MainActivity

Tags: java, android, kotlin

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.androidapp.diaryapp">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.DiaryApp"
        tools:ignore="ExtraText">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".PresenterNewTaskActivity"></activity>
        <activity android:name=".PresenterAboutTaskActivity"></activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

В AndroidManifest все прописано
Еще при этом не могу изменить название класса MainActivity через Refactor

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity">
```

.MainActivity при помощи интуитивного помощника добавляется, но горит красным

Код MainActivity:

```
    package com.androidapp.diaryapp

import android.content.Intent
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.View
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import com.androidapp.diaryapp.databinding.ActivityMainBinding
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference
import io.realm.Realm
import io.realm.RealmConfiguration
import io.realm.kotlin.where
import kotlin.collections.ArrayList

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var binding: AppCompatActivity
    private lateinit var database: DatabaseReference
    var adapterRcView:AdapterRcView?=null
    var selectedDate:String = ""
    var cFCalculator = ComFunCalculator()

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        val binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        Realm.init(this)

        val calendarView = binding.calendarView
        val rcViewTime = binding.rcViewTime

        calendarView.setOnDateChangeListener { view, year, month, dayOfMonth ->
            selectedDate = "$dayOfMonth-${month + 1}-$year"
            adapterRcView!!.updateAdapter(updateArrayListItem())
        }

        var list = ArrayList<ListItem>()
        list.addAll(fillArray(resources.getStringArray(R.array.hours),resources.getStringArray(R.array.descriptions)))

        rcViewTime.hasFixedSize()
        rcViewTime.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
        adapterRcView = AdapterRcView(list,this)
        rcViewTime.adapter = adapterRcView
    }

    fun fillArray(timeArray:Array<String>, descriptionArray:Array<String>):List<ListItem>{
        var listitemArray = ArrayList<ListItem>()
        for(n in 0..timeArray.size-1){
            var listItem = ListItem(timeArray[n], descriptionArray[n])
            listitemArray.add(listItem)
        }
        return listitemArray
    }

    fun updateArrayListItem():List<ListItem>{
        var timeArr:Array<String> = resources.getStringArray(R.array.hours)
        val selDateMill = cFCalculator.dateTimeToMillis(selectedDate, null)
        val config = RealmConfiguration.Builder().name("realmDB.realm").build()
        val realm = Realm.getInstance(config)


        val realmResults = realm.where<TaskRealmObjClass>().between("date_start",
            selDateMill!!, (selDateMill + 86400000 - 1)).findAll()

        var nextHourMill = selDateMill
        val realmList = ArrayList<TaskRealmObjClass>()
        realmList.addAll(realmResults.subList(0,realmResults.size))
        val listListItem = List(24) { ListItem(0, "", "") }



        for (i in 0 until timeArr.size){
            if (realmList.size>0) {
                for (j in 0 until realmList.size) {
                    if (realmList[j]?.date_start == nextHourMill) {
                        listListItem[i].id = realmList[j].id!!.toInt()
                        listListItem[i].time = timeArr[i]
                        listListItem[i].name = realmList[j].name.toString()
                        nextHourMill += 3600000
                        realmList.remove(realmList[j])
                        break
                    } else {
                        listListItem[i].id = null
                        listListItem[i].time = timeArr[i]
                        listListItem[i].name = ""
                        nextHourMill += 3600000
                    }
                }
            }else{
                listListItem[i].id = null
                listListItem[i].time = timeArr[i]
                listListItem[i].name = ""
            }
        }
        return listListItem
    }



    fun onClickAddNewTask(view: View){
        val intent = Intent(this,PresenterNewTaskActivity::class.java)
        startActivity(intent)
    }

    override fun onSaveInstanceState(outState: Bundle) {
        outState?.run {
        }
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState)

    }
}
```

build.gradle(Project)

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = "1.4.21"
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.2'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.4'
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.2"
        classpath "io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:10.3.1"

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

build.gradle(Module)

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
    id 'kotlin-kapt'
    id 'realm-android'
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
}



android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.androidapp.diaryapp"
        minSdkVersion 26
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding true
        dataBinding false
    }
    realm {
        syncEnabled = true
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.3.2'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.1'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:19.6.0'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-serialization-runtime-native:0.9.1'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.6'
    implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin:2.8.11.1'


}
```

Comment: горит красным и что пишет?

Comment: Писал, что нужно создать MainActivity class. Так и поступил, проблема решена, спасибо. Просто удалил старый класс, создал новый и перекинул туда весь код.